# Code excerpt freezes unexpectedly only when with full code

Tags: c++, c++11, freeze

#### What is causing my code to behave unexpectedly?

The program is freezing (not crashing) before it reaches expected part of the code. The program is fully contained inside `main()`, and isolating the whole code the expected statement makes it work correctly. Why is it happening?

---

I was coding a yet poor solution for [this codeforces problem](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/677/B), that I was intending to refine little by little. The problem is that curiously my program freezes when reading the input (like if it was an infinite loop, it doesn't crash). I tried both C++ and C++11 on GCC, and both of them froze. Tried [Ideone](http://ideone.com), and the same happened. It could be anything, except that I copied *everything* from the first include to the output line that would confirm that all the input was read and ran only this excerpt.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned uint;

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    uint n, h, k, buf;
    vector<uint> potatoes;

    cin >> n >> h >> k;

    for (uint i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> buf;
        potatoes.push_back(buf);
    }

    cout << "Letf\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This is a reduced version that contains all the lines that are part of the logic of the input stage. The expected input is

> 5 6 3
>
> 5 4 3 2 1

Here are the links for the [full code](http://ideone.com/FE7Wa1) and [the correctly working excerpt](http://ideone.com/ud7Nod).

Comment: Dont use `<bits/stdc+.h>`  -it is an internal header-. Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). **Use the debugger**

Comment: You do give the program the input? If you don't the program will just wait for the input and seem "frozen".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of course. You can see the ideone has input listed below the code.

Comment: @RawN I have read both C++ and C books. I know why not to use `bits/stdc++.h` and `using namespace std`. Doing this only gains time, and this means advantage in contests. I don't do this in the real world.

Comment: Build on your own system. Start with a debugger and step through the code line by line to see what's happening.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch debugger claims it skips the `cout` completely

Comment: The problem i think is because my logic itself is wrong, and it falls in an infinite loop before the output is flushed. Thus it looks like it never reaches that point at all. Right?

Comment: BTW, since you code for some Linux system, I would suggest to install Linux on your own laptop.

Comment: I do have Linux installed. Both Linux and Windows

Comment: Use `<< std::endl` on the end of your trace lines to make the output flush.

Comment: @TheDark thanks, that confirms what I've presumed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is your while (true) {...}. Your "algorithm" makes this loop infinitely.

And if you don't know, there is an Tutorial and source code for the round already 
http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/45181

Finally, please look carefully at the problem page. The Contest Materials part have useful things for you.

Comment: In addition that the output stream wasn't flushed, making it look like something else. I was aware of that part, but as I was studying I was trying to reach a solution before reading the tutorial.

Comment: Oh I see. Anyway, be careful with std::endl, althrough you use ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false), but the endl take more time than '\n' character. For some problems in Codeforce which output million lines, the endl make the source code solution Time limit exceeded but '\n' Accepted.

Comment: Yeah I see, will use it only for debugging purposes from now on